# How to append two String value in a new list using loop or other process in PYTHON?

Tags: python, append

I want to append two string value like **"orange" AND "purple"** both in new List called **NEW_SQUARE List**.
I did it through *and Operator* but it didn't work.

```
print("<==START of 2nd QUESTION==>\n")
squares = ['orange', 'orange', 'purple', 'blue ', 'orange', "purple", "orange",
           'blue ', 'purple', "orange"]
new_squares = []
x = 0
while x < len(squares) and squares[x] == "orange" and "purple":
    new_squares.append(squares[x])
    x = x + 1
print(new_squares)
print("\n<==END of 2nd QUESTION==>\n\n ")
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you're looking for.

```
while x < len(squares):
    if squares[x] == "orange" or squares[x] == "purple":
        new_squares.append(squares[x])
    x += 1
```

or

```
while x < len(squares):
    if squares[x] in ["orange", "purple"]:
        new_squares.append(squares[x])
    x += 1
```

Comment: Yes ig its something like this...thaks buddy

Comment: Anytime, @kamran_hccp. If this is the accepted answer, please mark it accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are trying to just filter the list to include only values of `orange` and `purple`.

```
In [1]: squares
Out[1]: 
['orange',
 'orange',
 'purple',
 'blue ',
 'orange',
 'purple',
 'orange',
 'blue ',
 'purple',
 'orange']

In [2]: new_squares = [square for square in squares if square in {"orange", "purple"}]

In [3]: new_squares
Out[3]: 
['orange',
 'orange',
 'purple',
 'orange',
 'purple',
 'orange',
 'purple',
 'orange']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
squares = ['orange', 'orange', 'purple', 'blue ', 'orange', "purple", "orange",
           'blue ', 'purple', "orange"]
new_squares = list(filter(lambda x: x in {'orange', 'purple'}, squares))
print(new_squares)
```

**Output**

```
['orange', 'orange', 'purple', 'orange', 'purple', 'orange', 'purple', 'orange']
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
  or operator 
  eg:
      while x < len(squares) and squares[x] == "orange" or "purple":
   
       
   use list 
   eg:
      while x < len(squares) and squares[x] in ["orange","purple"]:
```